# Running a custom command with Vim

Tags: vim

I want to be create an `artisan` command in Vim, so I can do something like:

```
:artisan make:migration create_blah_table --create=blah
```

And have it run the following:

```
ssh -t vagrant "cd /var/www && php artisan make:migration create_blah_table --create=blah"
```

Is this possible?

**Update**

The `make:migration create_blah_table --create=blah` bit could be anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `:help user-commands`:

```
It is possible to define your own Ex commands.  A user-defined command can act
just like a built-in command (it can have a range or arguments, arguments can
be completed as filenames or buffer names, etc), except that when the command
is executed, it is transformed into a normal Ex command and then executed.

For starters: See section |40.2| in the user manual.

          *E183* *E841* *user-cmd-ambiguous*
All user defined commands must start with an uppercase letter, to avoid
confusion with builtin commands.
```

You want `:command`

```
:com[mand][!] [{attr}...] {cmd} {rep}
                        Define a user command.  The name of the command is
                        {cmd} and its replacement text is {rep}.  The command's
                        attributes (see below) are {attr}.  If the command
                        already exists, an error is reported, unless a ! is
                        specified, in which case the command is redefined.
```

You can put this in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
command -nargs=* Artisan !ssh -t vagrant "cd /var/www && php artisan <args>"
```

And then use the `:Artisan make:migration create_blah_table --create=blah` command in ex-mode.

Comment: The `make:migration create_blah_table --create=blah` doesn't want to be hard-coded into the command. I want to be able to run `:Artisan whatever` and have that run `ssh -t vagrant "cd /var/www && php artisan whatever"`

Comment: Small Hadron Collider: whoops, missed that. fixed.

Comment: I'm getting a `E488: Trailing characters` error when I try to run e.g. `Artisan cache:clear`

Comment: I fixed a typo, try again?